# CATransform3D for get an Isometric view

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-graphics, isometric

Ok guys, after reading a lot of questions, I managed to get my hexagonal grid painted, not very well indeed, but it works and this is what I need. 
Now, my next step is to get this plane view in isometric view, something like this map:

http://www.issamtp.org/gnfGr.jpg

I hope that the way is to use a simple CAAffineTransform or CATransform3D, but I'm really stuck about this. Can someone help me?